# How Get Row ID of Sqlite table with Biggest Number value & Open it within Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm Absolute Beginner.

I have a Sqlite Table which has 5 Column and one of them is "time".

When user View Each of My Sqlite Table Rows, the "time" column update with current time so the always the last seen row has the biggest number ("time").

in my first Activity i want to make a button that open the last row with biggest "time" number.

in the Activity which user can see the row values, are some TextViews which fill with Sqlite row data and update them when user close the activity. and when user click one of listview items, the Row values send with putextra to Activity...

the problem is : I can't do put extra from first Activity Because There is a lot of staff in listview activity and I don't know what to do !!!

here is my Listview codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// Declare Variables
public static final String  ROW_ID     = "row_id";
private static final String TITLE      = "title";
private static final String COUNTS     = "counts";
private static final String TIME       = "time";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tablenotes";

private ListView            noteListView;
private CursorAdapter       noteAdapter;
private SQLiteDatabase      database;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));

    // Locate ListView
    noteListView = getListView();

    // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
    noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

    // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
    String[] from = new String[]{ TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

    // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
    noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_zekr, null, from, to);

    // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
    setListAdapter(noteAdapter);

}

// Capture ListView item click
OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

                                         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                                             // Open ViewNote activity
                                             Intent viewnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CounterActivity.class);
                                             viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
                                             startActivity(viewnote);
                                             finish(); //  test
                                         }
                                     };


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
    new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

    // Deactivates the Cursor
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.deactivate();

    noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);

    super.onStop();
}
```

here is my First page codes:

```
   btnlastz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
   Intent viewnote = new Intent(Firstpage.this, CounterActivity.class);

      //  what should i write here to open last ROW in sqlite?
      //                    startActivity(viewnote);

      }

    });
```

here is some part of my Activity that shows the sqlite values:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getLong(MainActivity.ROW_ID);
private class LoadNotes extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {

    // Calls DatabaseConnector.java class
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(CounterActivity.this); // Instance of DatabaseConnector Activity for make methods work! ahmad


    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
        // Pass the Row ID into GetOneNote function in
        // DatabaseConnector.java class
        dbConnector.open();
        return dbConnector.GetOneNote(params[0]);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        result.moveToFirst();
        // Retrieve the column index for each data item
        int TitleIndex = result.getColumnIndex(TITLE);
        int NoteIndex = result.getColumnIndex(NOTE);
        int CountsIndex = result.getColumnIndex(COUNTS);
        //            Log.i("Log", "onPostExecute - C is: " + C); ahmad
        int LimitsIndex = result.getColumnIndex(LIMITS);

        // Set the Text in TextView
        title_edit.setText(result.getString(TitleIndex));
        note_edit.setText(result.getString(NoteIndex));
        counts_edit.setText(result.getString(CountsIndex));
        limits_edit.setText(result.getString(LimitsIndex));

        result.close();
        dbConnector.close();

    }
}
```

if you need more data, just ask.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed The Problem with Saving RowID number on SharedPreferences.

When User Comes to CounterActivity, RowID Save itself to SharedPreferences.

and I Created A copy Of CounterActivity With name CounterActivity2.

In First Page Button, i puted CounterActivity2 Start Commands.

And at the Start of it, RowID Receiving from Sharedpreferences....

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String ROW_TITLE = "row_title";
public static final String ROW_COUNTS = "row_counts";
public static final String ROW_TIME = "row_time";
public static final String ROW_TABLE = "row_table";

 private String lastRowId,lastRowTitle, lastRowCount,
        lastRowTime, lastRowTableName;   

//above are global variable
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   /**
     * projection = DB projection is any else = null
     * sort = DB sort order is any else = null
     */

    /**
     * get all last row item
     * uri is your DB ContentUri
     */
    try {

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {

                /**
                 * This will return the last item of the DB
                 */
                lastRowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID));
                lastRowTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE));
                lastRowCount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COUNTS));
                lastRowTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TIME));
                lastRowTableName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_NAME));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Intent viewnote = new Intent(Firstpage.this, CounterActivity.class);
        viewnote.putExtra(ID, lastRowId);
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_TITLE, lastRowTitle);
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_COUNTS, lastRowCount);
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_TIME, lastRowTime);
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_TABLE, lastRowTableName);
        startActivity(viewnote);


        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
});

//CounterActivity.class
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 long rRowID = Long.valueOf(extras.getString(Firstpage.ID);
 long rTitle = Long.valueOf(extras.getLong(Firstpage.ROW_TITLE));
 long rCount = Long.valueOf(extras.getLong(Firstpage.ROW_COUNTS));
 long rTime = Long.valueOf(extras.getLong(Firstpage.ROW_TIME));
 long rTable = Long.valueOf(extras.getLong(Firstpage.ROW_TABLE));
```

Comment: +1 for try hard to help . the "uri" in Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri, null, null, null, null); is cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: in CounterActivity class. ROW_TITLE and other ROWS are unavalible ! the cant be accessed frem there ...

Comment: In do{ //  transfer the code to a static method and call this static method }. That will solve it.

Comment: 1+ Thank You, Ii Solve The problem with Sharedpreferences.  Thanks for your time. You helped me a lot.